# Don't know how to set up duplexer to print one page on each of 300 other pages

Tags: duplex

I have a single page document I want to print on each of 300 addressed cover sheets. Can this be done by duplexing without manual paper turning? If so how?

Comment: Does your printer have a duplexer mechanism to turn pages?  Mine does which is why I ask.

Comment: I'm either mis-reading or I'm not getting what your requirement is. You title seems to suggest you want to print on alternate pages, your question body just mentions 'a single page'. How would a duplexer be involved here? A duplexer is used to print on both sides of a sheet.

Comment: I have an inside of a document to be printed on the back of 300 addressed covers. Both sides need to be sent to the printer but I can't figure our to merge then or to duplex print them. Each cover has a different name and mailing address but the single page is the same for each inside.

Comment: My printer does duplex. It is not a problem where the inside sheet and cover are the same for all documents.

Comment: So, this isn't an issue with the duplexer, it's an issue with whatever you're using for mail merge. Your mail merger needs to be able to print multiple addresses with the same message on the other side, then send that to the printer. The printer will just print what it's told. If each job it gets is two-sided, that's what it will print.